# How to turn byte array into string array without any conversion

Tags: java, hex, byte

I have a byte array. I need to show its bytes on screen. How can I turn the bytes into a string representation without any conversion?

*By conversion, in this context I mean not decoding it into ASCII or any other equivalent encoding system

So for instance, if I have:

```
byte[] a = { 0x3F, 0x2C, 0x6A };
```

I'd like results like this:

```
String[] b = { "3F", "2C", 6A"};
```

Comment: ?? I thought I put Java tag. Why did somebody edit it?

Comment: Who had changed the tag from java to c#????

Comment: @AlexWien That's what the revision history is there for.

Comment: It is shown in the answers, but note that you need to use `0x` to tell Java that the literal is in hexadecimal representation, as thus: `byte[] a = { 0x3F, 0x2C, 0x6A };`. Then Java will know to convert from hex.

Comment: @Servy thanks I tried to look at the revision history but didnt see anything, probably my winXP (company forced) does not show it.

Comment: @l46kok: That's what you get for writing code which is valid C# but not valid Java. `string` isn't a type in Java. (And as I mentioned in my answer, you certainly *are* converting. You're taking a number and converting it to a hex representation. That's absolutely a conversion.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I've been programming in C# for a long time and just got started on Java, so my old habits carried on :( sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
byte[] a = { 0x3F, 0x2C, 0x6A };
String[] s = new String[a.length];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  s[i] = String.format("%02X", a[i]);
}
// s => ["3F", "2C", "6A"]
```

Comment: Does only work since java 1.5; hex strings are often  used in emebedded systems with java 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Byte[] a = {31,22,62}; 

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
```

Comment: I don't believe that will use hex, will it?